# `Task.async` times out on query inside `Ecto.Multi` in tests

Tags: elixir

I'm struggling to perform an async operation inside one of steps in `Ecto.Multi`. Here I'll present only minimal version to describe my problem:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  do my_function(repo \\ Repo) do
    Ecto.Multi.new()
    |> Ecto.Multi.run(:example, &perform_example(&1, repo))
    |> repo.transaction()
  end

  def perform_example(_changes_so_far, repo) do
    Task.async(fn -> repo.all(DataModule) end)
    |> IO.inspect() # 1.
    |> Task.await() # 2.
    |> IO.inspect()
  end
end

MyModule.my_function(Repo)
```

**1.** Seems to be working correctly as it yealds the `Task` Struct:

```
%Task{owner: #PID<0.352.0>, pid: #PID<0.354.0>,
      ref: #Reference<0.2903625078.3861118978.56327>}
```

**2.** Unfortunately raises the error:

```
     ** (EXIT from #PID<0.352.0>) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.353.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.2903625078.3861118978.56400>, true, 15000}, 5000)
         ** (EXIT) time out
```

Strangely enough, I've tried to perform this same code *outside* `Multi` and it worked correctly... Is this problem a problem with how `Multi` works?

I've tried to exercise this code just using the related functionality and this seemed to be working correctly. It's only the issue inside one of `Multi` steps when executing in test environment.

Comment: Sounds like deep nesting of tasks results in kinda race condition. Would you mind to try with [`Task.yield/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield/2) instead of `Task.await/2`?

Comment: I think this is related to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-ecto/WhenMB4R3Js. I get the timeout error with just `Task.async(fn -> Repo.insert(...) end) |> Task.await` inside a `Repo.transaction`.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa for suggestion, I've checked it and unfortunately this didn't work. Looks most likely like what michalmuskala suggested in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecto does not support multiple processes using a single transaction. It is not clear what the semantics of such a setup would be and what should happen if one of the processes fails.

Comment: So, you're rather suggesting it's not the problem with `Multi` it's rather problem with `transaction`. That makes sense. Thanks for suggestion!